# Calculate expectation and variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, expectation, uniform-distribution

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of independent RVs which are uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ interval. For $0<x\le 1$ we define
$$N(x):=\inf\{n:X_1+\dots+X_n\ge x\}.$$
Show that
$$\mathbb{P}(N(x)\ge n)=\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}.$$
Calculate $\mathbb{E}N(x)$ and $D^2 N(x)$.

I have absolutely no idea how to start. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You cannot compute $P(N(x)\geqslant1)$ and $P(N(x)\geqslant2)$? I do not believe you. And if you know every $P(N(x)\geqslant n)$, the expectation is a problem? Come...

Comment: Also note that $\mathbb{P}(N(x)\ge n)= \mathbb{P}(X_1+\cdots+X_n< x)$

Comment: So $P(N(x)\ge 1)=1$ and $P(N(x)\ge 2)=x$ But how to prove this formula: $P(N(x)\ge n)$

Comment: Hoda, shouldnt it be $P(X_1+\dots +X_{n-1} < x)$ in your formula?

Comment: Try induction, and conditioning on whether $N(x)\geq n-1$. Would that help?

Comment: I'll try induction tomorrow since in Poland it's almost midnight and post here. Thanks as for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditioning on $X_1$, one sees that, for every $x$ in $(0,1)$, $N(x)=1+N'(x-X_1)$ if $X_1\lt x$ and $N(x)=1$ if $X_1\geqslant x$, where $N'$ is distributed like $N$ and independent of $X_1$. Thus, the idea is to work with every $N(x)$ simultaneously.

First, $P(N(x)\geqslant1)=1$ for every $x$. Second, for every $n\geqslant1$,
$$
P(N(x)\geqslant n+1)=P(N(x)\geqslant n+1;X_1\lt x)=\int_0^xP(N(x-t)\geqslant n)\,\mathrm dt,
$$
from which one sees readily that the functions $u_n:x\mapsto P(N(x)\geqslant n)$ are uniquely determined by the initial condition that $u_1(x)=1$ and by the inductive relations that, for every $n\geqslant1$, $u_{n+1}(0)=0$ and $u_{n+1}'(x)=u_n(x)$. Surely you can deduce from this the distribution of $N(x)$.

To compute the expectation and the variance of every $N(x)$, use the fact that, for every integer nonnegative random variable $M$,
$$
E(M)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}P(M\geqslant n),\qquad E(M(M+1))=\sum_{n\geqslant1}2nP(M\geqslant n).
$$

Comment: You accepted this answer 6 minutes after I posted it. Are you sure you fully read it, fully checked it and fully understood it?

Answer (score -1):

We're calculating

$$P(N(x)\ge n| N(x) \ge n-1)=\frac{P(N(x)\ge n)}{P(N(x)\ge n-1)}$$
Obviously
$$P(N(x)\ge 1)=1=\frac{x^{1-1}}{(1-1)!}$$
Assume that
$$P(N(x)\ge n-1)=\frac{x^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}$$
So we have
$$P(N(x)\ge n)=P(N(x)\ge n| N(x) \ge n-1) \cdot P(N(x)\ge n-1)=\\P(N(x)\ge n| N(x) \ge n-1) \cdot\frac{x^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}$$
Now we only need to show that
$$P(N(x)\ge n| N(x) \ge n-1)=\frac{x}{n-1}$$

How can I show this equality? Any hint?